Create ec2 alarm status check for ssm agent
I am trying to add the status of ssm agent in an ec2 instance as a status check.
I was trying to create a cloudwatch alarm with ssm command failure as metric and attach it but it does not seem to work.

Can you provide more information? Like your filter pattern, metric details?
Have a look at this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/monitor-health-aws-systems-manager-agent-using-amazon-cloudwatch/
